# Access Javascript variable on the Backend in Rails

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, coffeescript

I have value in my Coffeescript file (`my_widget.coffee`), that I want to access and use at the backend in my ruby file `my_job.rb`.

How can I access this Javascript value from the backend in Rails?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't simply *share* and *access* variables from independent scripts that are running separately on the frontend and the backend. If you want to pass a value from the frontend to the backend, you need to use `Ajax`.

You can do something like this in `Rails`:

#### Use Ajax to pass the value

```
# app/assets/javascript/my_widget.coffee

$.ajax '/run_job',
  type: 'POST'
  data:
    my_var: variable_you_want_to_pass
```

#### Then create a new Route to receive it

```rb
# config/routes.rb

post '/run_job', to: 'jobs#run'
```

and add a controller method which receives the passed value and executes your `my_job.rb` with it:

```rb
# app/controllers/jobs_controller.rb

def run
  passed_variable = params[:my_var]

  # now invoke your my_job.rb with the 'passed_variable'
end
```

Comment: This is perfect! Worked right away! Hours of head-scratching solved in seconds!!